# User getting default Apache page instead of website - Safari/FF?

Tags: apache-2.2, mac, firefox, safari

I have someone complaining that www.archstl.org (a site I manage) loads fine from his Windows PC, but not on his Mac; and apparently he can't get it anywhere he takes his Mac, either...

I've heard of this happening to one other person, but I can't find an explanation. When they try loading it on their Mac using either Safari or FireFox, they get the default Apache page: "If you can see this, it means that the installation of the Apache web server software on this system was successful. You may now add content to this directory and replace this page."

I have had him ping www.archstl.org, and it always returns the proper IP address of our server (174.37.22.142), so I don't know what could be going wrong. It seems that our server is sending him the wrong page, plain and simple...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me with Safari 4.0.2.  <strike>Maybe he disabled HTTP/1.1 somehow or used some brain dead proxy server?</strike>

I see that a dns lookup for your site is reporting a IPv6 address of "::", which I think is the IPv6 equivalent of "localhost".  If you fix your DNS, or tell him to turn off IPv6, all should be well.

```
snowbird:~> host  www.archstl.org
www.archstl.org is an alias for archstl.org.
archstl.org has address 174.37.22.142
archstl.org has IPv6 address ::
archstl.org mail is handled by 20 smtp-relay.swbell.net.
archstl.org mail is handled by 10 mail.archstl.org.
archstl.org mail is handled by 10 mail2.archstl.org.
```

Comment: How does one lookup the IPv6 address? I've never done anything with v6, and know little to nothing about it...

Comment: I used the command "host www.archstl.org", which returned IPv4, IPv6 and MX addresses.

Comment: Awesome - I checked with the user, and this is precisely the problem... now to go about fixing it without control over the DNS entry (internal hassle) :-/

Answer (score 0):

Works for me "now" on OS X 10.5 with latest Firefox and Safari.